# aws s3 cp - only working with AdministratorAccess

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created a new user that I only want to have access to a limited number of resources, mainly to read from S3.

For some reason, it will only read from the s3 bucket if I provide the AdministratorAccess policy to the IAM user. Here is the command

`aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/my-config.json my-config.json`

**Error with AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess**:

`download failed: s3://my-bucket/my-config.json to ./my-config.json An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied`

But when I add **AdministratorAccess** it copies the file down just fine.

AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess has access to the `GetObject` action on ALL resources as well. Does anyone know why I'd be seeing this behavior?

Comment: To be honest, I couldn't figure out what the issue was, neither could my colleague. So we just wiped the bucket, created another with settings from a bucket we knew was working before, and now all is good

Comment: Actually never mind, ran into this issue again later when trying to pull remote terraform state and figured out the issue. Will post as an answer here

Answer (score 0):

The issue here had to do with the encryption key used to encrypt objects in the bucket. I am using KMS encryption (at rest) for objects in this S3 bucket. The new user I had created, had not been added to `Key Users` for this specific KMS key. This was preventing the user from using this key to decrypt the object during the `GetObject` action in S3. So that action specifically, failed which gave the (not-so-clear) error message.

To fix: add the IAM user as a key user under KMS and all works now. Phew..